# OneTimeWorkRequest not executed after add NetworkType.CONNECTED constraint in Oppo phone

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I've an issue when executing WorkManager in Oppo phone(Oppo A3s). After add NetworkType constraint, the request never executed even the phone is currently connected to A Wifi that has internet connection. Other phone don't have this issue. Anyone experience the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some OEMs are modifying the Android OS with additional limitations on the background processes that impact WorkManager functionality.
Please, open a bug on [WorkManager's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197) adding information on the device model and its OS version. Document there which problem you are experiencing and, possibly, provide a small sample to reproduce the issue.